# Why does the Linux kernel repository have only one branch?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, workflow

I'm a Linux beginner, so forgive me if this is the most obvious question you've ever heard.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/branches/all

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### Mainline kernel

First of all: don't use that github link (it's just a mirror). The actual repositories are located at [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/). You probably want to use Linus Torvalds' tree, which is [torvalds/linux.git](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/).

It's called **mainline** kernel, which means this tree is the one where actual development of next kernel version is happening. Although it has only **master** branch, you can checkout to any kernel version using tags. This command will show you all version tags:

```
$ git tag
```

You can checkout to desired tag like that:

```
$ git checkout v4.0
```

There is no need in a bunch of branches for mainline kernel, as development process in this tree never stops, and once new version is released, there won't be any back-porting to that version (inside mainline tree). So Linus sticks to tags (instead of branches) in this case.

### Stable kernel

There is also [linux-stable](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/) tree. "Stable" means that after release, some bug fixes would be back-ported to it. In this tree you should look for branches (rather than tags):

```
$ git branch -a
```

You can see branches like:

```
linux-4.9.y
```

where `y` suffix is just a placeholder for a bugfix version (because naming scheme is `linux-4.x.y`). Whenever you see `y` suffix -- it's a stable kernel branch. Some of those branches are LTS kernels (read [this](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html) for details).

In this case branches are needed because developers have to backport some bug fixes into released versions. So just tags are not enough here.

### Next kernel

It also should be mentioned that there is [linux-next](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git) tree. Here is the description from [kernel process documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/process/index.html):

> Before updates from subsystem trees are merged into the mainline 4.x tree, they need to be integration-tested. For this purpose, a special testing repository exists into which virtually all subsystem trees are pulled on an almost daily basis:
>
> https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git
>
> This way, the `-next` kernel gives a summary outlook onto what will be expected to go into the mainline kernel at the next merge period. Adventurous testers are very welcome to runtime-test the `-next` kernel.

### Maintainer trees

Back to the trees. Actually there are many of them, they are called *maintainers trees*. You can see all of them [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/).

You need to understand merging policy: only Linus can actually merge code to the mainline tree. You can see a lot of *merge commits* from him in git log. So if you want your patch to be applied to mainline kernel, you need to send it to [kernel mailing lists](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html) for review first. See [Documentation/SubmittingPatches](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches). Once your patch is reviewed and acknowledged by corresponding subsystem maintainer, he will apply it to his own tree. From there this patch will be merged to mainline kernel during next [merge window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_window). Linux kernel development model is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel#Development_model).

If you are interested in upstreaming your patches -- you may also want to go through [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org/UpstreamMerge) materials.

Comment: Seems like github mirror is not in sync anymore these days...

Comment: @malat it is in sync now.

Answer (score 4):

This repo only reflects the result of Linus' work merging hundreds of other branches into one main repo.

It does not keep those branches because there would be too many of them: the role of that repo is to be a reference.

Comment: And if you want to see what some of the other branches might look like, check out the "kernel" category at https://git.kernel.org/cgit/. Of course you can send in patches from anywhere (you don't even necessarily need to use git). The commit logs in the mainline repository often show where things come from.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen true: that GitHub repo is just a mirror.