# Linux kernel Intel video driver (i915) backlight brightness difference between releases

Tags: linux-kernel, gpu, backlight

I noted that the actual brightness of my laptop monitor is different on the same value(s) for backlight from the same range of available values when running Linux with kernel 5.4 vs. 3.13 (i915 driver). What might have changed to result in that? I like the 3.13 one better.

TL;DR

I noted backlight works differently on my laptop now on 5.4 kernel than on 3.13, range of values to write to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` is the same, but perceived brightness at `1` is much lower on 3.13 whereas max seems same.

I've found out most probably backlight on my laptop is controlled by i915 driver and source code in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/gpu/drm/i915 (it is a mirror per [Why does the Linux kernel repository have only one branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268332/why-does-the-linux-kernel-repository-have-only-one-branch), but on [kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/) I do not know how to open a tree of code to provide a web link to the driver).

How to find code that process input to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`? Hints on what to do next are also welcomed.

Comment: Looks like part of the GPU driver https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/backlight.html  For tree check here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.149/source/drivers/video/backlight

Comment: Many things can be the cause of that decision. You need to ask in the corresponding mailing list.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.